# $(this).data is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, custom-data-attribute

I've researched for the past 2 hours and cannot get this to work.

I am loading content via ajax and $(this).data is not working for me at all. If I change **this** to the actual class, then the content does load, however this is a portfolio so every button has a different url to load.

HTML:

```
<a class="button" href="#project-full" data-work-item="portfolio-open.html">View Project</a>
```

JS:

```
var loadUrl = $(this).data('work-item');

$(".button").click(function(){
    $("#project-full").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#project-full').offset(0,100).top }, 1000);
});
```

In theory, shouldn't the variable loadUrl grab the "portfolio-open.html" and pass it over to the loadUrl below? I am sure that I am missing something important, but from all the sources I've read this *should* work..

Comment: provide fiddle please.

Comment: what does $(this) refer to ..? can you show your complete code pls...!

Comment: what is `this` in the said context

Comment: Where does ajax_load come from?

Comment: $(this) should be encapsulated for particular event like Button.click =>{ now use this to refer to Button }

Comment: I assure you are so mistaken. Which sources?

Comment: this - refers to the current selector! please provide fiddle. Thanks

Comment: I was working on the fiddle but scrowler nailed it below.

Comment: Your this window not .button as you intended. Put var loadUrl = $(this).data('work-item'); inside the click event handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the `loadUrl` definition inside the click event handler, because `$(this)` should refer to the anchor element you've clicked:

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the default anchor action
    var loadUrl = $(this).data('work-item');
    $("#project-full").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#project-full').offset(0,100).top }, 1000);
});
```

Don't forget to prevent the default anchor action (redirecting).

Comment: Wow. The fact that you solved my problem within 2 minutes of posting is incredible. Thank you very, very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your code should be:

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var loadUrl = $(this).data('work-item');
    $(this.href).load(loadUrl);
    //$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#project-full').offset(0,100).top }, 1000);
});
```